# How to solve CORS Error in Angular and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors

I am doing a Fullstack Project, but I'm getting CORS Errors when I submit a create form from the frontend.

In my API, I have this File :

```
package com.example.PassMasterbackend.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                        .allowedMethods(HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                                HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                                HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                                HttpMethod.DELETE.name())
                        .allowedHeaders(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                                HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and here is my controller :

```
package com.example.PassMasterbackend.controller;

import com.example.PassMasterbackend.entity.Chest;
import com.example.PassMasterbackend.service.ChestService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/chests")
public class ChestController {

    @Autowired
    private ChestService chestService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Chest> getAllChests() {
        return chestService.getAllChests();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Chest getChestById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return chestService.getChestById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> createChest(@RequestBody Chest chest) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(chestService.createChest(chest));
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateCategory(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Chest chest) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(chestService.updateChest(id, chest));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteChest(@PathVariable Long id) {
        chestService.deleteChest(id);
    }
}
```

and here is my ChestService from Angular :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Chest } from './chest.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChestService {

  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/chests';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllChests(): Observable<Chest[]>{
    return this.http.get<Chest[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }

  getChestById(chestId: number): Observable<Chest> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${chestId}`;
    return this.http.get<Chest>(url);
  }

  createChest(newChest: Chest): Observable<Chest> {
    return this.http.post<Chest>(this.apiUrl, newChest);
  }

  updateChest(updatedChest: Chest): Observable<Chest> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${updatedChest.id}`;
    return this.http.put<Chest>(url, updatedChest);
  }  

  deleteChest(deletedChest: Chest): Observable<void> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${deletedChest.id}`;
    return this.http.delete<void>(url);
  }
}
```

I am still getting this error :
[image]

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error even with my WebConfig file ?
Thank you for your answers !!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve CORS problems:

- Expose the back end on the same port and host of the frontend
- Enable cross origin support on the back end

**Expose the back end on the same port and host of the front end**
You can use the configurations of your web server (nginx or apache or maybe IIS) to route particular requests to the back end. For example in nginx this can be done as follow

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

And in your front end prefix call the url as /api/API_PATH

**Enable cross origin support on the back end**
You can inform the back end to handle incoming requests to bypass cross origin security check using for example in java the [`@CrossOrigin`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) annotation (check the link for a complete official tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

While i agree with what Davide as written in his answer, there is another way that i use in my pprojects, I use proxy files in the UI as i can see you are running this app locally, you can do following,

1. create a proxy file in your code base like `proxy-dev.conf.json`, and the content of that file will look like below,

   `

   > ```
   > { "/api/*": {
   >     "target": "http://localhost:8080",
   >     "secure": false,    
   >     "logLevel":"debug",
   >     "changeOrigin":"true"
   > } }`
   > ```
2. run this with the command like `ng serve --proxy-config proxy-dev.conf.json`
3. Change the api url in your angular service such that URL only remain as `"/api/chest"` and localhost:8080 should nto be the part of url

More details you can find here at this link,
https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server